Why array can not be created in Kotlin by user inputs
Whenever I try to take input from user more than one I always face with this error: [Ljava.lang.Character;@3f91beef or the integer version of this error
Why is that? Here is the code I try to run by the way:
fun main() {
    val initArray = Array<Char>(3) { readln().first().toChar()- 1 }
    println(initArray)
}

I was trying to create a char array trying to take inputs from users.

Why do you think that message is an error?

Because whenever I try to run it it gives me an error code as I put it at the beginning of the question

As Ivo said, that's not an error code.  That's the format used by the toString() implementation on java.lang.Object (inherited by all Java objects unless overridden): it has the type of the object, in the JVM's internal form (where [ indicates an array, and L a reference type), a semicolon, and then the hex representation of the object's hashcode (which, unless overridden, is probably its address in memory).  It's a bit cryptic, but can be very useful for debugging etc.  If you want to see something else, you'll need to convert it to a string some other way.

It's not an error. It's literally what it looks like when you print an array. If you want nicer output you could use contentToString() on it, like
println(initArray.contentToString())

